ZIP files downloaded from iCloud are truncated
What causes ZIP files downloaded from iCloud to be truncated?  What can I do about it?
Problem
My wife emailed me batches of her iPhone photos that were missing from on my PC.  Each message has previews and a link to "Mail Drop Attachment" page on iCloud.  From there I download a ZIP file.  Windows reports "The Compressed (zipped) Folder [name] is invalid."
What I Tried

I tried to extract the photos using 7-Zip instead.  7-Zip managed to extract some of the photos (e.g., 9 out of 22) before reporting that the file ended unexpectedly.  From this I concluded that the downloaded ZIP files are incomplete.

I checked that file size shown on the iCloud download page (e.g., 8.6 MB) is consistent with the size Windows reports (e.g., 8.58
MB), and the filesystem reports (9,007,799 bytes).

I downloaded another copy of the ZIP file and compared it to the first.  The second download is byte-for-byte identical with the first.

I've searched for people experiencing similar problems. I found only one other post asking this question, but it received no answers.


More Background Than You Want
In January, my wife asked me to back up her iPhone photos onto my PC.  I connected the iPhone to PC over USB and copied the photos as though the iPhone were just another storage device.  That appeared to work.  The PC received a tree of monthly directories spanning 12 years and containing about 6000 JPG and MOV files.  I spot-checked dozens of the files, and they were all fine.
Recently, my wife wanted to confirm that the backup was complete.  I spot checked some of the more recent photos.  Although most of them are fine, many are not.  Windows says they're not valid JPGs.  A hex dump shows the invalid files don't start with the usual file header that all of the valid files seem to have.
Together, we started comparing the archive on my PC to the photos on her phone.  It took 90 minutes to cover the first two years, and we found many discrepancies:

Many photos were missing from the PC altogether.

Some photos on the PC are low resolution, but most are full size.

The PC archive has dozens of invalid JPG files that correspond to photos that are intact on the iPhone.  (The more recent the photo, the more likely it's corrupted.)

Strangely, a very small number of photos on the PC (that could only have come from the iPhone) no longer appear on the iPhone.

The photos on the PC are correctly bucketed chronologically into subdirectories like 201404__.  But the iPhone has several photos that appear a few months before or after they were taken.  For example, while the PC archive has all of her 2013 Christmas photos in 201312__, the iPhone shows one among preceding Thanksgiving (November) photos, and a couple others sprinkled in among photos from a subsequent event in March.  The rest of them are grouped in the correct spot chronologically.



Why don’t you just use iCloud and/or iTunes? What likely happened is you were attempting to copy what already was in the cloud (determined by iOS) as the physical original images were not actually on the phone itself but a placeholder. Impossible to determine if that’s the case based on your description though

So you describe two different backup sessions where you emailed copies to iCloud drops because of their size and where you manually copied the images to your desktop. Which one didn’t backup your images?

What does using iCloud and/or iTunes entail?  Are those websites or applications I'd have to install on a Windows.  (I have vague recollections of nightmares trying to get iTunes for Windows to function many years ago.)  My wife is the only Apple user in the house.  It's her iPhone and her iCloud account.

The "More Background Than You Want" section describes the initial attempt to get a copy of all her photos onto the PC.  When we realized that didn't work as well as we thought it had, we started this manual process of identifying photos that weren't copied and trying to transfer just the missing photos via email.  Now I have a couple dozen messages in my email with iCloud links to invalid ZIP files.

It looks like the issue occurred during upload of the files. Perhaps the phone lost connection before the upload was completed, or something entirely else. You have established that iCloud does not work for you. There are many alternatives (Box.com, DropBox, https://www.cloudwards.net/the-top-5-cloud-companies-with-large-free-service-plans/), and since we have no way of knowing what caused the issue, start over, using another cloud storage service.

@DrMoishePippik: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion. To start over with another cloud service would require getting the photos into that service. Apparently, the iPhone doesn't have full-resolution copies of all of the photos. Only iCloud does. (I don't think there's been a problem uploading problem to iCloud, since the photos sync between her iPhone and iPad.) Whether we want the photos in another cloud service or on a PC, the trick is still how to get them from iCloud.
